# How can I find login data in developer tools?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, developer-tools

I'm trying to use scrapy to post a reply on some website. So I have to log in with my own user account and password. Fortunately, scrapy only needs me to fill out the form like this:

```
FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]
```

But the problem is some websites name username as "username" while others name it as "user" or anything else. So how can I find out the login data by using the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox? Few months ago I could find it under "network". It suppose to look like this:
[image]
But now I tried several websites, none of them gives me the login data. Could anyone help? Thank you!
We can use github for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the problem is some websites name username as "username" while others name it as "user"

To handle different credentials field names try to use [loginform](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform).

```
def parse_login(self, response):
    data, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body,
                                        'login', 'password')
    return scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=dict(data),
                              method=method, callback=self.parse_next_page)
```

> But now I tried several websites, none of them gives me the login data.

Try to check [preserve log](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#working_with_the_console_history) checkbox on the `Network` tab.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Preserve log only keeps console history. It doesn't help find login information.

Comment: @user8314628 just check all request in the history

Comment: Ok, I find it. It is under the "Doc" tag instead of "XHR". Thanks a lot.